# Align images in specific order through CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have trying to align images in the following order

[image]

I have completed the left side properly. The issue I am getting is in adjusting Picture-4 (Picture in the above link).Picture 1,2 and 3 are aligned properly

```
 <div id='section_1'>
        <div className='typoSection'>
          <h3>Main Heading</h3>
          <h5>Sub-Heading</h5>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <span><img className='imgMargin' src={require('./assets/img/training_img1.png')} /></span>
          <span>
            <img className='imgMargin' src={require('./assets/img/training_img2.png')} />
            <img className='imgMargin' src={require('./assets/img/training_img3.png')} />
            {/* <img src={require('./assets/img/training_img4.png')} /> */}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.trainingContent #section_1,{
display: flex;
 }

 #section_1 p {
  line-height: 3.25vw;
  font-size: 21px;
  }

.typoSection {
  margin-right: 1.4vw;
   }
```